# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server-2005

I dont understand why the column 'OrderInfo.DateSold' is having an error for the following Stored proc. Please help me out.This is in Sql server 2005

```
SELECT DateSold,
       Rep.FirstName,
       Company,
       Contact,
       Phone,
       OPD.TotalAmount                              AS Sold,
       SUM(OPD.PaymentAmount)                       AS Collected,
       ( OPD.TotalAmount - SUM(OPD.PaymentAmount) ) AS Balance
FROM   OrderInfo
       INNER JOIN Order_PaymentDetails OPD
         ON OrderInfo.OrderID = OPD.OrderID
       INNER JOIN SalesRep_Info Rep
         ON OrderInfo.RepID = Rep.RepID
WHERE  OrderInfo.CommuniTeeID = @CommuniTeeID
GROUP  BY OrderInfo.Company
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because if you want to see in resulting set the column "Datesold" and so on, you need to group by this fields too:

```
SELECT 
    DateSold,
    Rep.FirstName,
    Company,
    Contact,
    Phone,
    OPD.TotalAmount AS Sold,
    SUM(OPD.PaymentAmount) AS Collected,
    (OPD.TotalAmount - SUM(OPD.PaymentAmount)) AS Balance 
FROM   
    OrderInfo
INNER JOIN 
    Order_PaymentDetails OPD ON OrderInfo.OrderID = OPD.OrderID
INNER JOIN 
    SalesRep_Info Rep ON OrderInfo.RepID = Rep.RepID 
WHERE  
    OrderInfo.CommuniTeeID = @CommuniTeeID
GROUP BY 
    OrderInfo.Company, DateSold, Rep.FirstName, Contact,
    Phone, OPD.TotalAmount
```